# Replace the id with master data value, suggest a common solution works for all masters?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

This is the minimal country & town array.

```
this.countries = [{name: 'Afghanistan', cotryId: '12'},   {name: 'Åland Islands', cotryId: '34'}];
this.towns =[{desc: 'Nizwa', townId: '1'},   {des: 'Ruwi', townId: '2'}];

this.hospitalService.getById(id).subscribe(response => {
 if (response['code'] == 'S0000') {
  this.addressList = response['result'];
 }
})
```

Here the adressList returns this json

```
[{cotryId:'12',townId:'1'},{cotryId:'34',townId:'2'}]
```

### .html file

```
<table class="table table-sm table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>slNo</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Town</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr *ngFor="let addr of addressList;let i=index">
        <td>{{i+1}}</td>
        <td>{{addr.cotryId}}</td>
        <td>{{addr.townId}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Master data is present for country and town, had to display the country & town names instead of Id in html page, How can I achieve this a common solution for both these scenario ?

can I use a pipe here, or any other better approach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing it in the `TypeScript` itself:

```
this.hospitalService.getById(id).subscribe(response => {
 if (response['code'] == 'S0000') {
  const result = response['result'];
  result = result.map(item => ({ ...item, 
                                townName: this.towns.find(town => town.townId === item.townId).name, 
                                countryName: this.countries.find(country => country.cotryId === item.cotryId).name}));

  // assign instance variable to result;
  this.addressList = [...result];
  console.log(this.addressList); // log it to see it is how you want it
 }
})
```

Then you should have access to them in the HTML.

```
<td>{{addr.townName}}</td>
<td>{{addr.countryName}}</td>
```

The key thing is to use `find` to cross reference the id's.